# Let $X_{1},.....,X_{n}$ a aleatory sample with density function: $f(x;\theta)=(1+\theta)^{\theta}1_{0<x<1} $ and $\theta>-1$. is consistent?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

I don't really know how to proof if it is consistent, but I did this and I don't know if someone can tell me if it is ok ::C

calculating the likelihood function:

L($\theta$)=f($x_{1},...,x_{n}$);$\theta$) = $\displaystyle\prod^{n}_{i=1}$($\theta$+1)$x_{i}^{\theta}$ =$(\theta+1)^{n}$$(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}$$x_{i})^{\theta}$

And since $\frac{d}{d(\theta)}log(L(\theta)) = \frac{n}{(\theta+1)} + \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}$$log(x_{i})$, then:

$\hat{\theta}= \frac{-n}{(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}log(x_{i}))} - 1$

Now we see if it is consistent, for that we first calculate the Fisher information,
then

$I(\theta)= -\mathbb{E} [\frac{\partial^{2} }{\partial\theta^{2}}log(f(X|\theta))]$
=-$\mathbb{E} [\frac{\partial^{2} }{\partial\theta^{2}}log(\theta+1) + \theta log(X)]$
= -$\mathbb{E} [\frac{-1 }{(\theta+1)^{2}}]$=$\frac{1 }{(\theta+1)^{2}}$

And now we calculate the variance of  $\hat{\theta}$

$Var(\hat{\theta})= \frac{1}{nI(\theta)}=\frac{(\theta+1)^{2}}{n}$

With this we can see if it is a consistent estimator, then:

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}Var(W_{n})=\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(\theta+1)^{2}}{n}=0$

Therefore $Var(\hat{\theta}_{n})$
$= 0$ is a consistent estimator.

Comment: $Var(\hat{\theta}_{n})\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ is not enough to say anything regarding consistency. Check the convergence of $E(\hat\theta_n)$.

Comment: $f$ is a density function, not a distribution function. And it is certainly not what it should be in your title.